# Need Help with Probability Reasoning

Tags: probability, solution-verification, independence

**Classify as true or false and explain why

(a) If $A$ and $B$ are two independent events satisfying $0 < P(A)$, $P(B) < 1$, then it is always true that $A$ and $B^c$ are independent events.

(b) $A$ and $(A ∩ B)$ are two mutually exclusive events if and only if $A$ and $B$ are mutually exclusive events.

(c) If $A$, $B$ and $C$ are events satisfying $0 < P(A)$, $P(B)$, $P(C) < 1$, then it is always true that

$P(A ∩ B ∩ C) + P(A ∩ B ∩ C) + P(A ∩ B ∩ C) + P(A ∩ B ∩ C) = 1 $

(d) If $A$ and $B$ are events satisfying $0 < P(A)$, $P(B) < 1$ and $P(A ∩ B) > P(A ∩ B)$ then it is always true
that

$P(A\mid B) \ge P(A^c\mid B)$**

For part **(a)**, I believe that this is true, because both events have a chance of occurring between $1$% and $99$%. By making it these bounds, this makes it so the event of both of them happening is not $0$ or $1$.

For part **(b)**, I believe this is false. If $A$ and $B$ are mutaully exclusive events, this makes the probability of both of them happening at the same time $0$. This would make $(A ∩ B)$ invalid, since the event can never occur given the circumstances.

For part **(d)**, I was thinking about using algebra to try and formulate a direct proof, but I'm not exactly sure what I should do.

Any help and clarification is appreciated.

Comment: Check what you've written for errors.  (a) doesn't make sense.  The premise that $A$ and $B$ are independent events is the same as the conclusion that $A$ and $B$ are independent events.

Comment: @JMoravitz sorry about the error. Thank you for the heads up.

Comment: You write "*for part a,... chance of occurring between 1%-99%*"  That is not what $0<P(A)<1$ means... Something which occurs with probability $0.000000001\%$ is still something which occurs with greater than zero probability.  Do not think that all probabilities are multiples of $1\%$.  As for your attempt and conclusion for (a), you seem to have completely missed the point of what "independent events" are.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a lot to unpack here and misconceptions to correct.

Let's start with some definitions.

When talking about probability, we have a probability space containing subsets of outcomes from our sample space and we call these subsets "Events."  We can assign a real number as a value to each of these events, *including the empty event*.  In order for such a probability space to be valid, certain nice properties must hold, such as the probability of the empty event (*aka the "impossible event"*) must be zero, the probability of the sample space as a whole must be $1$, and the probability of the union of two disjoint events (*aka mutually exclusive events*) must be equal to the sum of their respective probabilities.  From these, several more properties can be proven and follow such as how $\Pr(A\cup B) = \Pr(A)+\Pr(B)-\Pr(A\cap B)$ and $\Pr(A) = 1- \Pr(A^c)$ etc...  More on those can be found elsewhere.

We can talk about some important relationships between events.

We define *$A$ and $B$ are "mutually exclusive" events* to mean that $A\cap B = \emptyset$.  Recall the axiom mentioned above that this implies that if $A$ and $B$ are mutually exclusive events we will have $\Pr(A\cup B) = \Pr(A)+\Pr(B)$.  In general, if $A$ and $B$ are not mutually exclusive events we don't necessarily have $\Pr(A\cup B) = \Pr(A)+\Pr(B)$, it could be less.

We define *A and B are "independent" events* to mean that $\Pr(A\cap B) = \Pr(A)\times \Pr(B)$.  This can be shown to be equivalent also to $\Pr(A\mid B) = \Pr(A)$ and that $\Pr(B\mid A) = \Pr(B)$.  Note that while $\Pr(A\cap B) = \Pr(A)\times \Pr(B)$ may be true for independent events, this is *not* true for any other events.

---

(a) Suppose that $A$ and $B$ are independent events.  (*The condition that $0<\Pr(A)<1$ and $0<Pr(B)<1$ is not necessary here, so I will ignore it, but to emphasize what I mentioned in comments, probabilities can be any real values between zero and one, and that includes numbers smaller than $1\%$ and irrational values etc...*)

This implies that $\Pr(A\cap B) = \Pr(A)\times \Pr(B)$.

Now... we are asked to verify whether $A$ and $B^c$ are also independent events.  Note that $\Pr(A) = \Pr((A\cap B)\cup (A\cap B^c)) = \Pr(A\cap B)+\Pr(A\cap B^c)$ since $(A\cap B)$ and $(A\cap B^c)$ are both mutually exclusive events who union to the event $A$ and so the sum of their probabilities is equal to the probability of their union, again by the axiom mentioned above.

So, by subtracting $\Pr(A\cap B)$ from both sides we have $\Pr(A\cap B^c) = \Pr(A)-\Pr(A\cap B) = \Pr(A) - \Pr(A)\times \Pr(B) = \Pr(A)(1-\Pr(B)) = \Pr(A)\Pr(B^c)$, using all of the aforementioned properties.  As such, we do indeed have the probability of the intersection of $A$ and $B^c$ is in fact the product of their respective probabilities and so they are indeed independent.

Note... this has nothing to do with "*the event of both of them happening is not 0 or 1.*"  You can have independent events whose probability of both happening is zero (*in which case they were both impossible events*) or whose probability of both happening is one (*in which case they were both sure events*).  What was important here was that the probability of both happening being equal to the product of their respective probabilities.

---

(b) Suppose $A$ and $A\cap B$ are mutually exclusive events.  That means by definition that $A\cap (A\cap B) = \emptyset$.  Well, from elementary set theory, we know how intersections work (*if you don't go back and review those chapters*) and that intersection is associative.  So, rearranging the parentheses by associativity we have $(A\cap A)\cap B = \emptyset$, and then by absorption (*that $A\cap A = A$*) we have that $A\cap B = \emptyset$.  This is however precisely the definition of $A$ and $B$ being mutually exclusive so $A$ and $A\cap B$ being mutually exclusive does indeed imply that $A$ and $B$ will be mutually exclusive as well.

In the reverse direction, we can effectively reverse all of those arguments to get $\emptyset = A\cap B = (A\cap A)\cap B = A\cap (A\cap B)$ in order to show that $A$ and $B$ being mutually exclusive does imply that $A$ and $A\cap B$ are also mutually exclusive.

"*This would make $A\cap B$ invalid...*"  No, that doesn't make it "invalid"... it just makes $A\cap B$ an *impossible event*.  It is still a perfectly valid event however, just one who occurs with zero probability.

---

(c) clearly has a typo, you wrote $A\cap B\cap C$ four times.  As written it is obviously false.  Just pick any example where $\Pr(A\cap B\cap C)\neq \frac{1}{4}$, for example when $A=B=C$ and $\Pr(A)=\frac{1}{2}$.

---

(d) This also clearly has a typo.  $\Pr(A\cap B)>\Pr(A\cap B)$ is never true.  A number cannot be strictly greater than itself.  Presumably this should be $\Pr(A\cap B) > \Pr(A^c\cap B)$ implying that $\Pr(A\mid B) > \Pr(A^c\mid B)$

Well... this should be clear when you remember the definition of conditional probability and that $\Pr(A\mid B) = \dfrac{\Pr(A\cap B)}{\Pr(B)}$

You have then $\Pr(A\mid B) = \dfrac{\Pr(A\cap B)}{\Pr(B)} > \dfrac{\Pr(A^c\cap B)}{\Pr(B)} = \Pr(A^c\mid B)$

Comment: When you code $\Pr(A)$ as `\Pr(A)` rather than `Pr(A)` the effect is not only to prevent italicization but also to get proper spacing, thus: $$ \begin{align} 5\Pr(A) \\ (3+5)\Pr(A) \end{align} $$ Contrast this with $$ 
\begin{align} 5 Pr(A) \\ 5\text{Pr}(A) \end{align} $$ Here the second line is coded as `5\text{Pr}(A)` and you don't see proper spacing.

Answer (score 1):

I explain to you why (a) is true based on a proof argument , I think you can (and should) do the same for the others.

Because $A \cap B^C$ and $A \cap B$ are mutually exclusive events the first step is justified :

$$P((A \cap B^C) \cup (A \cap B)) = P(A \cap B^C)+P(A \cap B) = P(A \cap B^C)+P(A)P(B)$$

the last step is correct because $A$ and $B$ are indipendent.

But you know also that :
$$P(A \cap B^C)+P(A)P(B) = P(A) $$

since $(A \cap B^C) \cup (A \cap B) = A$.

Then, rearranging you obtain :

$$P(A \cap B^C)= P(A)(1-P(B))= P(A)P(B^C)$$

which is the definition of indipendence.